# How do I find out which input modes include a specified uft-8 character?

Tags: character-encoding, input-method

Using the input mode latin-1-prefix I can enter "~a" which gives me "ã". I am looking for a similar way to enter the characters "āēīōū" (vocals with bars).

So my question is:

1. What input mode does allow me to input the characters "āēīōū"?
2. Is there a general method to retreive a list of input modes that include a specified character?

Comment: How about `C-x 8 C-h` to get a list of possible diacritics?

Comment: I just wrote this comment to the answer you deleted: 
For most (if not all) the Spanish characters you are using, you can simply go `C-x C-m C-\ ` and select `latin-1-prefix`. `C-h C-\ ` then shows you how to enter them. Unfortunately I don't know which input mode the characters "āēīōū" belong to that I need for typesetting Latin.

Comment: Thank you very much -- I'm now in the process of revising my user configuration files to free up some of the keyboard shortcuts I had previously assigned to dedicated Spanish characters -- Emacs is a never ending learning curve.  :)

Comment: Good to hear it helped. However your `C-x 8 ` way doesn't seem to include the characters I need, but thank you for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no general way to find out what input methods give access to a given set of characters.  An input method is written in Emacs Lisp, and it can use any Emacs Lisp primitives to build characters.  From a quick look under `lisp/leim/quail`, I see that the `latin-4-postfix`, `latin-4-alt-postfix`, and `TeX` input methods include vowels with macrons.

The whole point of Emacs, however, is that it is extensible — so why don't you define your own input method?  Say, something like the following:

```
(quail-define-package "macron-underline" "Macron" "MC")

(quail-define-rules
 ("_a" ?ā)
 ("_e" ?ē)
 ("_i" ?ī)
 ("_o" ?ō)
 ("_u" ?ū)
 ("__" ?_))
```

Then say `M-x set-input-method macron-underline`, and you're all set.

(Aside.  Many, many years ago, under the old, pre-Unicode MULE, I designed and implemented the `polish-slash` input method.  While the code included in Emacs is no longer my original code, I'm still using it today.  End of aside.)

Comment: Thank you! You are right it might be the easiest to just define my own input mode. Didn't even think of this, but makes perfect sense!